# MVVMCross boolean binding

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I would like to know how to bind a boolean property that is inside my viewmodel to a a control in my view using MVVMCross.An example would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of samples, including many that bind to booleans in:

- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/
- https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross with corresponding videos indexed at https://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

I'd suggest:

- starting with something like ApiExamples - you'll find at least one example of a checkbox-bool binding there: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ApiExamples
- watching some of the N+1 videos at https://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

Comment: Hi Stuart, I have tested public bool IsEnabled {set; get;} and then  local:MvxBind="Enabled  IsEnabled" and it works like a charm. So my next question is, what happens if I want to have an ICommand binding and property binding at the same line.                            eg:local:MvxBind="Enabled  IsEnabled,Click SearchCommand". I have tested this unsuccessfully. What is the legal approach in these cases?

Comment: I'll be the nasty guy answering: bindings are separated by ; and not ,